# Elementor: how to send data via webhook?

Tags: php, wordpress, webhooks, elementor

How to add field value to Elementor Pro Form Widget Webhook URL?

I have tried:

`name [name] [field id = "name"] array["fields"]["name"]["value"]`

And how to catch data from this webhook?

`form name: form_01 field id/name: name http://***/webhookformtg.php?name=[field id="name"]&tel=[field id="tel"]&vopros=[field id="vopros"]`

Comment: Better to ask first to google what is webhook? Sending and getting data is same in PHP.